# How do I find the B-matrix of the reflection across the x-y plane?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: This is the problem]

The answer is 
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        -1 & -1 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
but I don't know how they found this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $v_1 = (0,0,2)^T, v_2 = (1,1,1)^T$ and $v_3 = (-3,4,0)^T$. Reflecting $v_1$ across the $xy$ plane, we get $$(0,0,-2)^T = -1\cdot v_1 + 0 \cdot v_2 + 0 \cdot v_3.$$
The coefficients above are going to form the first column of our $\mathcal{B}$ matrix.

Following the same process, we have that if we reflect the vector $(1,1,1)^T$ across the $xy$ plane, we get the vector $$(1,1,-1)^T=-1\cdot v_1 + 1\cdot v_2+ 0\cdot v_3.$$

Similarly, if we reflect $(-3,4,0)^T$ across the $xy$ plane, we get the vector itself. Thus:
$$ (-3,4,0)^T = 0\cdot v_1 + 0\cdot v_2 + 1\cdot v_3.$$

Hence:
$$\mathcal{B} = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}.$$

Practically, this means that if we apply the transformation described by the matrix $\mathcal{B}$ to our original vectors $v_1, v_2, v_3$ we get the transformed vectors as columns. Indeed:
$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & - 3 \\ 0 & 1 & 4 \\ 2 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \cdot 
\begin{bmatrix} -1 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & - 3\\ 0 & 1 & 4\\ -2 & -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$